# Why is this giving me a float value in the second column and creating two rows?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlrd

My code opens an excel workbook and copies the first two rows from the first 4 sheets on the workbook.

With this code, it produces 5 different columns when if you refer to the desired output I want it to be 2 different columns.

Another thing I don't understand is why the 3rd and 4th column is a float. Why is it making it a float?

I tried to create a better question because my other questions have not been well-received so if you have any feedback that helps too.

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xlsx')

    data = []

    for i in range (0,5):
        sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(i)
        data.append([sheet.cell_value(row, 0) for row in range(sheet.nrows)])
        data.append([sheet.cell_value(row, 1) for row in range(sheet.nrows)])


    transposed = zip(*data)
    with open('file.txt','w') as fou:
        writer = csv.writer(fou, delimiter='\t')
        for row in transposed:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

**Output:**

```
F800    00      F8C8    32.0    
F804    01      F8CC    33.0
F808    02      F8D0    34.0    
F80C    03      F8D4    35.0
F810    04      F8D8    36.0    
F814    05      F8DC    37.0
F818    06      F8E0    38.0
```

**Desired Output:**

```
F800    00          
F804    01      
F808    02      
F80C    03      
F810    04        
F814    05      
F818    06            
F81C    07          
F8C8    32 
F8CC    33
F8D0    34   
F8D4    35
F8D8    36  
F8DC    37
F8E0    38
```

Comment: I see several potential problems. (A) You say there are 4 sheets but doesn't `range (0,5)` have 5 elements? (B) `Data` looks like it will be a list of lists `[S0R0, S0R1, S1R0, S1R1, ... S4R1]`, where each SmRn is a list with data from row n of sheet m. So I'm surprised your not getting 10 elements in each row when you zip!. (C) I think you need `zip(data)` --- (that is, without the asterisk). (D) I'm not familiar with `xlrd` so consider adding the `xlrd` tag to get more expert attention.

Comment: A) you are right it is 5 not four. I have updated the question to say 5. D) I will add the XLRD tag. Thanks for the feedback I appreciate it

Comment: I tried removing the asterix but that only made it worse. It was a good idea though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = [[], []]

for i in range (0,5):
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(i)
    data[0].extend([sheet.cell_value(row, 0) for row in range(sheet.nrows)])
    data[1].extend([sheet.cell_value(row, 1) for row in range(sheet.nrows)])


transposed = zip(*data)
with open('file.txt','w') as fou:
    writer = csv.writer(fou, delimiter='\t')
    for row in transposed:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

`data` was initialized to contain 2 empty lists. The lists are *extended* in the `for` loop. This should get you the correct number of output columns.

For the float value problem, Excel stores numeric data as floats (no ints). So before exporting you may need to use Excel's formatting features to get rid of the decimals or convert the numbers to text.

Hope that helps.